# Rails 6.0.1 - Trix Editor Parameters not transmitted from form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trix

The added or changed data from a Trix editor field is not submitted/ transmitted.

```
<%= form_with(model: @comment, local: true) do |form| %>
  <div class="form-group">
  <h4>Titel</h4>
  <%= form.text_field :header, class: "form-control border-top-0 border border-right-0 border-left-0 rounded-0 p-0" %>

  <br/>
  <h4>Inhalt</h4>
  <%= form.trix_editor :comment %>

  <%= form.text_field :tonie_id, value: tonie_id, hidden: true %>
  <%= form.text_field :user_id, value: current_user.id, hidden: true %>
  <%= form.check_box :private %> privater Kommentar

  <br/>

  <%= form.submit "speichern ",class: 'btn btn-success' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

looking into my logs I get the following:

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"xxxx", "tcomment"=>{"header"=>"title", "comment"=>"", "tonie_id"=>"49", "user_id"=>"1", "private"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"speichern "}
```

Any idea, what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This has been discussed here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37399

You can fix by manually assigning ids to each of the rich text fields. Like this below:

```
form.rich_text_area :first_description, id: 'trix_first_description'
form.rich_text_area :second_description, id: 'trix_second_description'
form.rich_text_area :third_description, id: 'trix_third_description'
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This may happen if there are multiple forms of the same model type on your page. I also encountered the same problem. I think it may be caused by duplicate ID.

When multiple rich text editors of the same model type appear on the same page, only the first one can be used normally. After other windows input content, they will be filled into the hidden tags of the first window, so when submitting , The data is null

Sorry i don't know how to express my thoughts in english, hope you understand my speech